# Programming in C in Visual Studio Community 2017 on Mac

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am taking C course and was required to work on VS community 2017. I've been trying to install it on my mac, and the process seem to go ok but I can't find an option to write in C, or to open a project with "Visual C".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Visual Studio for Mac does not support C or C++. Your options seem to be either Visual Studio Code or running Windows in a virtual machine on your Mac. You can check this post for details: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef99e9f5-2a48-423b-b6c0-fa5617d7c63d/how-do-i-get-c-to-work-on-visual-studio-for-mac?forum=visualstudiogeneral